# How to make table td tr auto width based on text length?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a table with width 100%, how can I set TD and TR based on text length auto width? I used width: auto  but it doesn't work. here's my code:

```css
.hoverTable {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.hoverTable td {
  padding: 7px;
  border: #4e95f4 1px solid;
}
/* Define the default color for all the table rows */

.hoverTable tr {
  background: #b8d1f3;
}
/* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */

.hoverTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffff99;
}
.hoverTable th {
  background: #b8d1f3;
}
```

```html
<table class="hoverTable">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Some Text here</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>This is text length example and text</td>
    <td>Item 1B</td>
    <td>Item 1C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 2A</td>
    <td>Item 2B</td>
    <td>Item 2C</td>
  </tr>

  <th colspan="3" class="width: 100%;">Some Text here</th>

  <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 3A</td>
    <td>Item 3B</td>
    <td>Item 3C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 4A</td>
    <td>Item 4B</td>
    <td>Item 4C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 5A</td>
    <td>Item 5B</td>
    <td>Item 5C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see in the **This is text length example and text**   the width is not based on text length, how can I set width based on text length..

I mean auto width based on text length ?

Thank you

Comment: It is a little bit unclear what you are trying to achieve. So you want a table of width 100% of its container, but each column width being adjusted to its text content? At some point one or several columns need to fill the gap so that the table fills 100% of its parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
.hoverTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

So just remove the `width: 100%;` and it will work. The table will now be rendered dynamically.

Fiddle: [Click](http://jsfiddle.net/epywtvjf/)

Comment: The `table-layout: fixed` has little to do with it, your removal of the `width: 100%` has. The fixed layout might even mess with the layout, read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout